# GHCi - Haskell Compiler Error - /home/user/.ghci is owned by someone else, IGNORING

Tags: linux, haskell, chmod, ghci, chown

While trying to change the ~/.ghci file to my configurations this error appeared when I opened GHCi.

```
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
*** WARNING: /home/user is writable by someone else, IGNORING!
WARNING: /home/user/.ghci is owned by someone else, IGNORING!
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and GHCi 7.6.3. What can I do to solve this problem so that my confiurations work?

My settings are based on this reddit link: http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/144biy/pretty_output_in_ghci_howto_in_comments/

Comment: Well, who owns the file in question?

Comment: here is the return from "ls -l ~/.ghci":
-rwxr-xrwx 1 root root 1083 Jul 10 00:47 /home/magamig/.ghci

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that the owner of the directory is "user"

```
ls -lah /home
```

if it is owned by someone else, change the ownership:

```
sudo chown user:user -R /home/user
```

Edit: I noticed that root owns ~/.ghci so you must change it using sudo.

Comment: tried it, different error:
*** WARNING: /home/magamig is writable by someone else, IGNORING!
*** WARNING: /home/magamig/.ghci is writable by someone else, IGNORING!

Comment: Is your home directory writable by another group?  Can you just do `chmod g-w /home/user` ?

Comment: Check /etc/passwd to see which group belongs to the same user as megamig.

cat /etc/passwd | grep megamig
cat /etc/passwd | grep GROUPID

Comment: "magamig" is my username and the return from cat in magamig is:
magamig:x:1000:1000:magamig,,,:/home/magamig:/bin/bash

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

`$ chmod 600 ~/.ghci`

This has removed the permission to use it for any groups other than me.

Comment: This also fixed a similar issue with intero: `/.stack-work/intero is writable by someone else, IGNORING!`, by setting the permissions like this.